# xamarin System.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Im trying to draw a graph on an android phone screen. I've created the classes I needed in a windows forms application to make the testing easier and faster. My application uses the System.Drawing class

When im trying to apply my code in a xamarin android project, the System.Drawing class apparently doesn't contain the "Graphics", "Font", "Pen" and "Brushes" classes. The System.Drawing.Graphics class is documented in the xamarin android api, but yet I can't get it to work.

Do i have to import a diffrent class to be able to use these classes, or do i have to change the code i wrote?

My Graph class (only draws the x and y axis + numbers): [Graph Class](http://pastebin.com/ThQLrhmd)

```
//author Frank Keuning
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables.Shapes;
using Android.Views;
using System.Drawing;

namespace App2
{
    public class Graph
    {
        Graphics g;
        int height;
        int width;
        int step;
        int x;
        int y;

        Point yNumPoint;
        Point xNumPoint;
        Font font = new Font("Verdana", 7.5f);
        Pen pen = Pens.Black;

        public Graph(Graphics gph, int hght, int wdth, int stp, int xStart, int yStart)
        {
            g = gph;
            height = hght;
            width = wdth;
            step = stp;
            x = xStart;
            y = yStart;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x, height);
            g.DrawLine(pen, x, height, width, height);
            drawNumbers(g);
        }

        void drawNumbers(Graphics g)
        {
            yNumPoint = new Point(0, height - y);
            xNumPoint = new Point(x, height + y);
            int yNumValue = 0;
            int xNumValue = 0;
            while (yNumValue <= height)
            {
                g.DrawString(yNumValue.ToString(), font, Brushes.Black, yNumPoint);
                yNumValue += step;
                yNumPoint.Y -= step;
            }

            while (xNumValue <= width)
            {
                g.DrawString(xNumValue.ToString(), font, Brushes.Black, xNumPoint);
                xNumValue += step;
                xNumPoint.X += step;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste the code. Most of us wont take the time to follow the link, which could break. Copy and paste it. Also see stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some help on how much to include

Comment: i added my code, thanks.

Comment: System.Drawing.Graphics is tied to W32 and the GDI - systems that do not exist on Android.  You will need to use the Android drawing APIs to perform similar functions in Android, even with Xamarin

Comment: As the above guy said. If you want to draw cross platform I recommend you use the "SkiaSharp" api's to do the drawing: https://blog.xamarin.com/cross-platform-2d-graphics-with-skiasharp/

Another solution that might be even better is to use an existing graphing library (there are a few out there) you can search the Xamarin component store for libraries that will draw the graphs and make them all pretty for you!

Answer (score 1):

For my projects I had the same requrement: to use native Graphics in Android.

I've came up with a porting layer. It runs relatively fast, but some features may be not yet implemented:

https://github.com/cail/AndroidDrawing

Answer (score 1):

One of my colleages ran into the same problem when he literally tried to copy-paste WinForms-code into Xamarin. It's not that easy, sadly.

As you mentioned System.Drawing exists, but it's simplified. The reason behind this is that Xamarin Android is running on Mono (see [Mono docs](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/drawing/)) and thus not .NET. The reason you're missing packages is simple as some have mentioned here; these namespaces and classes simply don't exist. As many other point out here there are alternatives in the form of nuget-packages or Xamarin Components.

A good starting point would:

1. [Xamarin Component store](https://components.xamarin.com/)
2. [NuGET (deeplink)](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Xamarin%20Drawing%20Chart)

Please note that I advise you to use readily-available libraries. From my experience trying to recreate WinForms (or the stuff it does) is futile as mobile development works completely different. I'd advise you to find a charting library rather than a drawing library, but that's just my €0,02.

Add-on: If you are trying to build something that works crossplatform make sure to check out the crossplatform libraries (they work in a Portable Class Library, or .NET Standard Library if you're lucky). That'll help you get started in every mobile project type rather than having to recrease the graphs with different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library that has cross platform support. Xamarin has ported the skia librery under the name SkiaSharp and you can now use it for android, iOS and windows

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/drawing/